# Discord Music Bot interrupts music playback on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, discord, pycord

I have a music discord bot written in `Python`. Bot plays music from YouTube using the `yt-dlp` library and `ffmpeg`.

Everything worked fine, but a couple of days ago the bot began to interrupt the playback of any tracks for `~80%` duration, crashing with an error:

```py
[tls @ 0x6e3b440] Error in the pull function.
[tls @ 0x6e3b440] IO error: Connection reset by peer
[https @ 0x6e37900] Will reconnect at 720896 in 0 second(s), error=Connection reset by peer.
```

I have the latest version of `py-cord=2.4.1` and `yt-dlp==2023.3.4` installed.  When the bot is launched on my computer, the bot plays all the tracks to the end, so the problem is clearly not in the **code and not in the libraries**.

I suspect something is wrong with `ffmpeg`, so I tried installing different buildpacks, but that didn't solve the problem.

At the moment I have the following installed:

```py
https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git
https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
```

What could be the problem and how to solve it?  Why did this problem appear only on hosting?  Why didn't this happen before?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a network issue, maybe try this options inside your ffmpeg options which i used to get around this:

```
ffmpegopts = {
    'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
    'options': '-vn'
}
```

I set `reconnect_delay_max` to 5 meaning that if 5 seconds pass, it will try to reconnect.

Comment: I apologize for not specifying this in the text of the question, but these parameters have already been specified :(

Comment: oh well then i idk actually what would fix this, but make sure to edit your question and include this information followed with some code